# How to make a call to new html page when click on button in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I am a newbie to RoR. I have created a new HTML5 page and want to integrate this into an existing RoR application. I want to call the HTML5 page when a button is clicked. How can I do this?

Is there a direct integration or I need to write my own controller and do something else.

Please tell me how to integrate the page with my existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the HTML code into a view, create a route in config/routes.rb, create an controller and the action you have defined in the route and that's it. But I guess you should learn the basics of Ruby on Rails since this is the most basic thing in RoR to do.

Start here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/